# Vertical spacing in floats

Tags: spacing, floats

I am using a float inside the text. As I found out, using `\intextsep` I could set space above and below the float and the texts. But when I am using `\setlength{\intextsep}{5mm}`, the space below the float is more than the one above it. Why they are not equal?

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.0.0beta1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% A simple dot to overcome graphicx limitations
\newcommand{\lyxdot}{.}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength{\intextsep}{5mm}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0mm}

\setstretch{2}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{centering}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{\lyxdot \lyxdot /Pictures/fedora}
\par\end{centering}

\caption{}

\end{figure}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get equal space above and below a float if I use `\setlength{\intextsep}{5mm}`. Please edit your question to include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows the behaviour you describe.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. Note that an MWE should be a complete document, starting from `\documentclass`, i.e. it should include your preamble. If I insert your code into a document, I get slightly more space *above* the float. Please turn your example into a complete document, so we can properly assess what's happening.

Comment: @Jake Thanks, and sorry again! I already added a working sample which produce same result for me! Hope you could help! I Just started learning LaTex.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's an explanation of what's going on, using a step-wise approach. First of all, consider the following toned-down version of your example code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\setlength{\intextsep}{0mm}
\begin{document}
Line 1: Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{\lyxdot \lyxdot /Pictures/fedora}
%  \caption{This is a caption}
\end{figure}

Line 2: Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\par
Line 3: Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
\end{document}
```

All the packages have been removed and the code slightly modified (the `centering` environment has been changed to `\centering` that has a scope within the `figure` environment; numbered lines of `Text Text...`; `demo` package option to [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) that allows anyone to compile the example and replace all images with a black rectangle; commented out the `\caption` command). This is what the output looks like.

[image]

Note how the baseline of `Line 1` is "tight" to the figure. If you zoom in, you'll see that the text is literally touching the figure. This is because of `\setlength{\intextsep}{0mm}`. Why then is `Line 2` not "tight" to the figure from the bottom? It actually is! In fact, the distance from the bottom of the figure to the baseline of `Line 2` is exactly the same as the baseline skip from `Line2` to `Line 3`. It may seem like it isn't "tight", but baseline to baseline (or the `\baselineskip`) it is.

This marginal difference is exaggerated when adding the other components of your original example, such as the [`setspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) and `\setstretch{2}` while still keeping `\setlength{\intextsep}{0mm}`:

[image]

However, the `\baselineskip` between the figure and `Line 1` is still the same as the `\baselineskip` between `Line 1` and `Line 2`, as expected. Adding a `\caption` further increases this gap visually:

[image]

However, as before, the `\baselineskip` from the bottom of the caption (the bottom of the `g` and `p` characters) is exactly the same as the `\baselineskip` from `Line 1` to `Line 2`.

If you want to correct for this, you need to add the required skip to the top of the float, for example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\setlength{\intextsep}{0mm}
\begin{document}
Line 1: Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text \par \kern 5pt

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{\lyxdot \lyxdot /Pictures/fedora}
  \caption{This is a caption}
\end{figure}

Line 2: Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\par
Line 3: Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
\end{document}
```

Here `5pt` seemed reasonable. Or, if you want to automate this, then you can use the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{figure}{\kern 5pt}%
```

Note though that this will place a `5pt` gap between the figure and text even if your figure ends up at the top of the page. Such manual interaction is usually not good style, even if it may seem visually inaccurate. LaTeX will do a good enough job in terms of spacing.

---

**Edit**: As @Jake suggested, a much better approach would be to modify the skip below the caption (or `\belowcaptionskip`) to remove some of the overly visual `\baselineskip`. In the following example, an `\intextsep` of `5pt` is set, with `\belowcaptionskip` set to `-\baselineskip+1.6ex` (to get rid of `\baselineskip` and add a "normal line" height; obtained via experimentation when `\intextsep=0pt`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{setspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace
\begin{document}
\setlength{\intextsep}{5pt}%
\setstretch{2}%
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-\baselineskip}\addtolength{\belowcaptionskip}{1.6ex}%
Line 1: Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{\lyxdot \lyxdot /Pictures/fedora}
  \caption{This is a caption}
\end{figure}

Line 2: Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\par
Line 3: Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since the issue is aggravated by the OP's use of `setstretch{2}`, instead of adding white space at the top, I would have suggested "cancelling" the unwanted vertical space below the figure by setting `\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-\baselineskip}
\addtolength{\belowcaptionskip}{1.5ex}` (i.e. reduce the space by a whole `baselineskip`, then add the space that a "normal" line of text would take up). This has the advantage of adapting to any changes of the `setstretch` parameter, and not requiring an external package. Can you see any issues with this approach?

Comment: @Jake: That's much better. Not sure about the look when a single line of text may end up below a figure `[h]` at the bottom of a page. However, this may be rare. Contextual rewording or perhaps a `\needspace` might solve this problem on a as-needed basis.