# Deleting extra vertical space when figure caption is not given

Tags: tables, spacing, captions

I wonder how I can get rid of the space created by deleting the table title (highlighted in red)? I used the example from: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1279

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[belowskip=-15pt,aboveskip=0pt]{caption}

\setlength{\intextsep}{10pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{document}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \fbox{Test figure 2}
\end{figure}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your example does not match the image. If there is no caption, no extra space is added. Show the example that generates the image. And please don't send us to some like, they rot over time.

Comment: But I did it with this example. However I deleted the wrong part of the code! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell: add some negative vertical space, for example `\vspace{-<lenght>}`

The floats (figures and tables) add space before and after the environment.
The length `\intextsep` controls such space. (examples 1 and 2)

In the example 3 the spaces above and bellow the caption are tailored to squeeze the caption, suppressing the extra spaces using `belowskip` and `aboveskip`

In the last example, a figure without a caption, the extra space is suppressed using `\vspace{-1em}`

See [Vertical spacing in floats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32617/161015)

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\setlength{\intextsep}{10pt plus 2pt minus 2pt} % Space above and below  text floats. Default 12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt for a 10pt document

\begin{document}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \fbox{Test figure and caption (1)}
    \caption{Normal caption}
\end{figure}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \fbox{Test figure no caption (2)}
\end{figure}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \fbox{Test figure with a squeezed caption (3)}
    \captionsetup{belowskip=-14pt,aboveskip=3pt}
    \caption{Squeezed caption}
\end{figure}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \fbox{Test figure no caption \& vspace (4)}
    \vspace{-1em}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\end{figure}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

\end{document}
```